# Issue about phpmyadmin, mysql and dreamweaver

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I have an issue that I could not figure out. I need to clarify that I am very new to phpmyadmin, mysql, databases and dreamweaver.

Currently, I have one table (book) which contains these attributes (ISBN(primary key), title, author, publisher, price etc) in phpmyadmin

I have the other table (users) which contains these attributes (username (primary key), password, name, DOB etc) in phpmyadmin too.

Let me explain the series of steps for my webpages first. An user logs in on the log in page successfully, and he will be directed to the main page, then he will type or select his search terms, then the results page will display the relevant results in the master list, then he will select the specific result to go to the detailed page containing more information.

What I want now is to create a reservation page. If the user likes the specific book, he can click reserve it, and will be directed to the reservation page.

I intend to have these search textfields: Username, Title, Price, and Number of books.

How can I let the username textfield to be automatically filled with the username as the user has logged in at the login page initially.? Also, how can I let the title and price textfield to be automatically filled with the relevant title and price, as the user has clicked reserve it at the specific detailed page? I intend that the user just key in number of orders and press submit button. My 3rd database (reservation) will capture the info of username, title, price, and number of orders. Do i use insert record or update record?

Do i create a relational table in phpmyadmin by linking it with the keys from tables (book and users)? Will this be a many to many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionId to display username in the textbox...
use javascript to automatic fill up the title and price....
for the 3rd databse u should use insert record and create 3rd table too...

Comment: Hi @shwet dalal, May you elaborate more on how can i go about doing this cos I am quite new to dreamweaver and phpmyadmin? Thanks!

Comment: get id of logged in user in $_SESSION['user'] and than use that id to display username in textbox....

Comment: you dont knw any thing regarding dreamweaver that doesn't matter. It is just IDE. that doesn't affect your code...

Comment: Hi @shwet dalal, by default the session variable of username is MM_Username. That is in my loginpage which is my 1st page, but my reservation page is 4 pages away from the loginpage, can i still use the default session variable? Anw, how do i use javascript to auto fill up the title and price. Thanks for the help!

Comment: unless you haven't cleared the session object you can use it any where in your project that's the benefit of using session....

Comment: When u get title nd price than with javascript u can write code to insert value in both textbox

Comment: let ur title textbox id is txt_title than with javascript code u can write like this...var title = document.getElementById('FROM WHERE U GET THE VALUE');      document.getElementById('txt_title').value = title;